# azure Stream analytics isfirst and last query

Tags: azure-stream-analytics, stream-analytics

I have the payload something like below. I need to get the first distinct  batch values for every 1 minute period. Please let me know how to achieve this in stream analytics using isfirst and lag or last

Output like:

BATCH=01,"2015-01-01T00:00:01.0000000Z"
   BATCH=02,"2015-01-01T00:00:03.0000000Z"
   BATCH=03,"2015-01-01T00:00:06.0000000Z"
   BATCH=01,"2015-01-01T00:00:14.0000000Z"
   BATCH=02,"2015-01-01T00:00:18.0000000Z"
   BATCH=03,"2015-01-01T00:00:22.0000000Z"
   BATCH=01,"2015-01-01T00:00:27.0000000Z"
   BATCH=01,"2015-01-01T00:00:31.0000000Z"

```
Pay Load:
    [{
            "Payload": {
                "Make": "BATCH1",
                "VAL": "01",
                "TS": "2015-01-01T00:00:01.0000000Z"
            }
    },
    {
    "Payload": {
            "Make": "BATCH1",
            "VAL": "01",
            "TS": "2015-01-01T00:00:02.0000000Z"
        }
    },
    {
        "Payload": {
            "Make": "BATCH1",
            "VAL": "02",
            "TS": "2015-01-01T00:00:03.0000000Z"
        }
    },
    {
        "Payload": {
            "Make": "BATCH1",
            "VAL": "02",
            "TS": "2015-01-01T00:00:04.0000000Z"
        }
    },
    {
        "Payload": {
            "Make": "BATCH1",
            "VAL": "02",
            "TS": "2015-01-01T00:00:05.0000000Z"
        }

    },
    {"Payload": {
            "Make": "BATCH1",
            "VAL": "03",
            "TS": "2015-01-01T00:00:06.0000000Z"
        }

    },
    {"Payload": {
            "Make": "BATCH1",
            "VAL": "03",
            "TS": "2015-01-01T00:00:07.0000000Z"
        }

    },
    {"Payload": {
            "Make": "BATCH1",
            "VAL": "03",
            "TS": "2015-01-01T00:00:10.0000000Z"
        }

    },
    {"Payload": {
            "Make": "BATCH1",
            "VAL": "03",
            "TS": "2015-01-01T00:00:11.0000000Z"
        }

    },
    {"Payload": {
            "Make": "BATCH1",
            "VAL": "03",
            "TS": "2015-01-01T00:00:12.0000000Z"
        }

    },
    {"Payload": {
            "Make": "BATCH2",
            "VAL": "01",
            "TS": "2015-01-01T00:00:13.0000000Z"
        }

    },
    {"Payload": {
            "Make": "BATCH2",
            "VAL": "01",
            "TS": "2015-01-01T00:00:14.0000000Z"
        }

    },
    {"Payload": {
            "Make": "BATCH2",
            "VAL": "01",
            "TS": "2015-01-01T00:00:15.0000000Z"
        }

    },
    {"Payload": {
            "Make": "BATCH2",
            "VAL": "01",
            "TS": "2015-01-01T00:00:16.0000000Z"
        }

    },
    {"Payload": {
            "Make": "BATCH2",
            "VAL": "01",
            "TS": "2015-01-01T00:00:17.0000000Z"
        }

    },
    {"Payload": {
            "Make": "BATCH2",
            "VAL": "02",
            "TS": "2015-01-01T00:00:18.0000000Z"
        }

    },
    {"Payload": {
            "Make": "BATCH2",
            "VAL": "02",
            "TS": "2015-01-01T00:00:20.0000000Z"
        }

    },
    {"Payload": {
            "Make": "BATCH2",
            "VAL": "02",
            "TS": "2015-01-01T00:00:21.0000000Z"
        }

    },
    {"Payload": {
            "Make": "BATCH3",
            "VAL": "02",
            "TS": "2015-01-01T00:00:22.0000000Z"
        }

    },
    {"Payload": {
            "Make": "BATCH3",
            "VAL": "02",
            "TS": "2015-01-01T00:00:23.0000000Z"
        }

    },
    {"Payload": {
            "Make": "BATCH3",
            "VAL": "02",
            "TS": "2015-01-01T00:00:24.0000000Z"
        }

    },
    {"Payload": {
            "Make": "BATCH3",
            "VAL": "02",
            "TS": "2015-01-01T00:00:25.0000000Z"
        }

    },
    {"Payload": {
            "Make": "BATCH3",
            "VAL": "02",
            "TS": "2015-01-01T00:00:26.0000000Z"
        }

    },
    {"Payload": {
            "Make": "BATCH4",
            "VAL": "01",
            "TS": "2015-01-01T00:00:27.0000000Z"
        }

    },
    {"Payload": {
            "Make": "BATCH4",
            "VAL": "01",
            "TS": "2015-01-01T00:00:28.0000000Z"
        }

    },
    {"Payload": {
            "Make": "BATCH4",
            "VAL": "01",
            "TS": "2015-01-01T00:00:29.0000000Z"
        }

    },
    {"Payload": {
            "Make": "BATCH4",
            "VAL": "01",
            "TS": "2015-01-01T00:00:30.0000000Z"
        }

    },
    {"Payload": {
            "Make": "BATCH5",
            "VAL": "01",
            "TS": "2015-01-01T00:00:31.0000000Z"
        }

    }
    ]
```

Comment: Hi,mbr. Actually,i can't get your concern.You want to implement something like `TOP`  in the 1 minute window?

Comment: Hi Jay, thanks for the response and sorry that I was not clear.in a minute window there can be multiple VAL changes for each batch ID.ex:
In minutes i can get

Make:batch1,Val:01,
Make:batch1,val:01,
Make:batch1,val:02,
Make:batch1,val:02
××××××××××××
Make:batch2,val:01,
Make:batch2,val:01,
Xxxxxxxxxx

From this I need filter only  val for every batch changes and no duplicates.i need
Output as
Make:batch1,val:01
Make:batch1,val:02
Make:batch2,val:01
Ofcourse with the original  timestamps  as I mentioned my first post

Answer (score 0):

I tried to summarize your requirement as below:

Example input,in a minute window there can be multiple VAL changes for each batch ID:

> Make:batch1,Val:01, Make:batch1,val:01, Make:batch1,val:02,
>   Make:batch1,val:02 ×××××××××××× Make:batch2,val:01,
>   Make:batch2,val:01, Xxxxxxxxxx

Desired output,only val for every batch changes and no duplicates:

> Make:batch1,val:01 Make:batch1,val:02 Make:batch2,val:01

Answer is divided into 2 parts:

1.Collect data in a static period, you could use built-in [Tumbling Window function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/stream-analytics-query/tumbling-window-azure-stream-analytics?toc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fstream-analytics%2FTOC.json&bc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fbread%2Ftoc.json) as below:

2.No built-in ASA function like distinct to filter the duplicate.I'd suggest you using `GROUP BY`, `MAX`,`ASA UDF`([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-javascript-user-defined-functions)) to approaching your result.

SQL:

```
 SELECT g.Payload.Make,g.Payload.VAL,max(udf.convertdate(g.Payload.TS)) as TS
    FROM geoinput g TIMESTAMP BY g.Payload.TS
    GROUP BY g.Payload.Make,g.Payload.VAL, TumblingWindow(Duration(minute, 1))
```

Test output:

[image]

BTW,i just use below code inside UDF

```
var date = new Date(datetime);
    return date.getTime();
```

---

Another workaround,you could collect all the data during 1 minute then use [Azure Function as Output.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-with-azure-functions) In the Azure Function, you could process data as you want. Such as use JSON object to store the data.Key-Value structure could filter duplicate rows.

Comment: Thanks Jay for the response. Your logic works but in the first case i need TS as date time format.Yes we could consider the second option aswell but i have to do this in stream analytics alone. any inputs on first approach with proper time stamp?